# MySQL incorrectly returns ALL records with IN clause

Tags: mysql

In MYSQL v8, I recently **removed** a field named "email" from my `usertenant` table.

However, during development I found an existing query that is still using the email field and to my surprise it is now returning ALL rows and ignoring my where clause.  Can you help me to understand why?

For example, suppose I'm trying to get records for `campaigns` run for a single `usertenant`:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    campaign
WHERE   campaign_email IN (SELECT `email` FROM usertenant WHERE tenantid = 99)
```

This returns **ALL** records from the `campaign` table for all tenantids.

However, if I run just the SELECT email FROM usertenant WHERE tenantid = 99, it returns an error because the email column doesn't exist.  An error also occurs if I change the IN clause to an inner join. FYI, in this example tenant 99 would exist only once in the usertenant table.

Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: I suspect that there is a column `email` in the table `campaign`.

Comment: need to see some sample data

Comment: honestly the chance that you found that bug is very remote